# Regex match everything excluding pattern

Tags: regex

I am very new with Regex

I have a file that looks like this:

```
  401190: some text1
  401194: some text2
  this text should be ignored
  40119a: some text3
  40119e: some text4
  4011a2: some text5
  4011a8: some text6
```

I wish to get the everything between 401194 (included) and 4011a2 (excluded).
My regex currently looks like this:

```
/((?=401194)(.*)(?=4011a2))/s
```

Now I would like to match everything between them excluding lines that do not start with a digit.
So basically everything but

```
/^[\D]*/gm
```

so that it does not match the "this text should be ignored".

How can I combine the two expressions?

Comment: What is your regex tool or flavor?

Comment: You can't skip a portion of text when capturing it into a single group. You will have to do it in two steps. BTW, your regex is better written as `/401194.*?(?=4011a2)/s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make use of a lookbehind with an infinite quantifier like .NET, python PyPi regex module or Javascript [where supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) you might use:

```
(?<=^(?=401194).*(?:\n(?!4011a2|401194).*)*)\d.*(?=(?:.*\n)*?4011a2)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is at the left is

  - `^(?=401194).*` Assert start of string, where you assert that is starts with 401194
  - `(?:\n(?!4011a2|401194).*)*` Repeat matching all lines that do not start with either 4011a2 or 401194
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `^\d.*` Match a line that starts with a digit
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, asser what is at the right is

  - `(?:.*\n)*?4011a2` Match as least as possible lines until matching 4011a2 at the start
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mb8oqp/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=^(?=401194).*(?:\n(?!4011a2|401194).*)*)^\d.*(?=(?:.*\n)*?4011a2)/gm;
const str = `401190: some text1
401194: some text2
this text should be ignored
this text should 123 be ignored
40119a: some text3
this text should 123 be ignored
40119e: some text4
4011a2: some text5
4011a8: some text6`;

console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[0]));
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if there are digits in the middle of the text? For instance, replace "this text should be ignored" by " this text should 123 be ignored".  The "123 be ignored" will also be matched

Comment: @johanDa9u it could be like this https://regex101.com/r/mb8oqp/1 I will update the answer. I forgot the anchor `^` before the digit.

Comment: This is really great regex to solve this problem using dynamic length lookbehind

Comment: @johanDa9u According to your question that you have removed, this is an example of 2 steps https://jsfiddle.net/q3csg56f/

Comment: @johanDa9u: For future may I suggest you to always mention your language/tool/regex flavor with a `regex` tagged question. I asked this question below your question also but there was no response.